# Wallpaper cycling option disabled

Tags: macos, wallpaper

In **Desktop & Screen Saver**, the **Change picture** and **Random order** checkboxes are completely disabled. See scrennshot.

[image]

What does it mean? How do I enable these features?

Answer (score 1):

Just pick "normal desktop pictures", the one you've picked is dynamic wallpaper, the new type of wallpaper that will change itself.

Comment: aha, well I specifically wanted a dynamic wallpaper, and change it every day. So you're saying dynamic wallpapers don't support cyclic rotations?

Comment: You want to cycle different sets of dynamic wallpaper? You can't do that i think.

Comment: OK, if you're sure, can you update your answer accordingly, so I can validate it